# Segmentation/Matching arabic characters

Tags: opencv, image-processing, ocr, arabic

I have many pictures like this and i want to segment each character alone by using any matching technique.

[image]

So I manually segmented a letter of this word , and i used a simple image difference of this image with slide in the original image of the same size.

[image]

This didn't work for all the words due to the variation of the character in the word itself as sometimes the window of the original image includes other characters.

So what's the optimum technique to match or to get the characters of the original image ?

Comment: There is no optimum. It depends on speed or robustness requirements, personal preferences...
What's your goal? Character recognition?

Comment: Yes Character recognition

Comment: Take a look at **Graph Transformer Networks**.